# How can I find whether the type of a field is ObjectId or not and convert this field to string in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, objectid

I have a collection which has over 300,000 records in it . I made a mistake and some of this records have wrong field like this :

```
"ParticipantId" : ObjectId("56578b12aa9c5817303f306f"),
```

However the field should be type of string. Some record has correct field like this :

```
"ParticipantId" : "56578b12aa9c5817303f306f",
```

What I want to do is to find the records has wrong fields and change their value as string. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to change it to a string? `ObjectId` is typically what you want here as it's more efficient.

Comment: "ParticipantId" is not main id of this record.It shows relation with "Participiants" collection.I used it as string in my whole code. I do not want to change the codes. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator to find documents where type of "ParticipantId" is `ObjectId` and update those using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operations and the `.str` attribute.

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.collection.find({'ParticipantId': { '$type': 7 } } ).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ '_id': doc._id }).updateOne({
        '$set': { 'ParticipantId': doc.ParticipantId.str }
    });
    count++;
    if (count % 100 === 0) {
        // Execute per 100 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Clean up queues
if (count > 0) bulk.execute();
```

---

You may also want to change "ParticipantId" to `ObjectId` where "ParticipantId" is string  instead.

```js
db.collection.find( { 'ParticipantId': { '$type': 2 }}).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( {
        '$set': { 'ParticipantId': ObjectId(doc.ParticipantId) }
    });
    count++;
    if ( count % 100 === 0 ) {
        // Execute per 100 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Clean up queues
if ( count > 0 ) bulk.execute();
```

---

In version older than 2.6 you need to iterate over the cursor and [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) your documents.

```js
db.collection.find( { 'ParticipantId': { '$type': 7 } } ).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collection.update( 
        { '_id': doc._id }, 
        { '$set': { 'ParticipantId': ObjectId(doc.ParticipantId) } }
    );
} )
```